# onChange handler for Object.keys().map in React to update object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, mapping

I have a component with an empty metadata object at DOM load, the server sends data to fill the empty metadata object with properties that will be assigned values within the form. I am able to iterate through the meta data and see multiple input fields correctly labeled yet when I got to input something it either doesn't change anything and the console logs the single keystroke or it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined`. The title field handles the change just fine.

My code:

```
class Item extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      metadata: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ... //retrieve metadata from server
    this.setState({
      metadata: metadata
    });
    console.log(metadata); //{meta1: "", meta2: "", meta3: "", meta4: "", meta5: "", …}
  }

  handleChange = (field) => {
    return (value) => this.setState({ [field]: value });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      title,
      metafield
    } = this.state;
  }

  return(
    //code to start form

    <TextField value={title} onChange={this.handleChange(title)} label="Title" type=text />

   {Object.keys(metadata).map(function(key) {
     return (
      <TextField key={key} value={metadata[key]} onChange={this.handleChange({key})} label={key} type=text />
     )
   })}

   //code to end form
  )
}
```

I'm sure it's because the `handleChange` isn't equipped to handle changes on object properties but I'm not sure how to access that layer. I've tried binding a `handleMetadataChange` function on the constructor and use `e.target` to assign the values but the failing behavior persists.

Comment: It's a binding issue, try the following: `Object.keys(metadata).map((key) => {` arrow functions automatically bind to `this`

Comment: @HMR this definitely helped but does not provide a full solution, I'm still working through that. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs:

1. handleChange sets state like this: `this.setState({ [field]: value});` but the values are in state.metadata not in state.
2. In render
   you    get `metafield` from state but initially you set `metadata`
   and in    handleChange you don't use any of it.
3. You always re create onChange for TextField even if nothing has changed, this causes needless DOM re renders.

Here is a working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      metadata: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.resolve().then(() =>
      this.setState({
        metadata: { x: 'x', y: 'y' },
      })
    );
  }

  handleChange = (field, value) =>
    //you forgot you are setting metadata of state
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      metadata: { ...this.state.metadata, [field]: value },
    });

  render() {
    const {
      metadata, //you used metaField here but it's metadata
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(metadata).map(key => (
          <TextField
            key={key}
            value={metadata[key]}
            onChange={this.handleChange} //always pass the same handler function
            changeKey={key} //added for optimization
            label={key}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
//make textfield a pure component as it only receives props
//  You could call this TextFieldContainer and not change TextField at all
const TextField = React.memo(function TextField({
  value,
  onChange,
  changeKey,
  label,
}) {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      times rendered: {rendered.current}
      <label>
        {label}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={value}
          onChange={e =>
            onChange(changeKey, e.target.value)
          }
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: With 2 event handlers, handleTitleChange and handleChange, I was able to make this works for me. I don't understand where the recreation comes from though I definitely see it happening once I add the "time rendered" counter to all inputs. Could you elaborate on that or send a relevant link?

Comment: @mezzomix In my code this.handleChange is always the same `this.handleChange === this.handleChange` so I always pass the same on every render. In your code you pass a different reference on every render `this.handleChange("key") !== this.handleChange("key")` That is why react re renders components that didn't change. Maybe look up why the usecCallback hook exist.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this at the end of your constructor: `this.handleChange = this.handleChange .bind(this);`

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method

[Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: I have done as you instructed and see a value being passed onto `state` but not as intended: `state: { title: '', meta1: "foo", metadata: {meta1: '', meta2: '', meta3: ''...}}`. Should I have a separate function for handling changes on the metadata so it doesn't create a new object onto `state` and instead edit that within `metadata` like it's supposed to?

Comment: Separate the handleChange fro title and the metadata because how would you decide if it belongs to the title or to the metadata.

Comment: You don't need to bind handleChange because it's an arrow function and automatically bound: `handleChange = (field) => {`. However; the function passed to map is not bound: `{Object.keys(metadata).map(function(key) {`, so that should be: `{Object.keys(metadata).map((key) => {`

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Item extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      metadata: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ... //retrieve metadata from server
    this.setState({
      metadata: metadata
    });
    console.log(metadata); //{meta1: "", meta2: "", meta3: "", meta4: "", meta5: "", …}
  }

  handleChange = (field,e) => {
   let temp  = this.state.metdata;
   temp[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({metadata: temp });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      title,
      metafield
    } = this.state;
  }

  return(
    //code to start form

    <TextField value={title} onChange={this.handleChange(title)} label="Title" type=text />

   {Object.keys(metadata).map(function(key) {
     return (
      <TextField key={key} value={metadata[key]} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e,key)} label={key} type=text />
     )
   })}

   //code to end form
  )
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea to mutate state in handleChange, if this ever gets optimized with pure components then you don't get re renders as React doesn't see mutated value as a change. The onChange is also needlessly re created when nothing changes and that causes DOM re renders (it's used to handle an onChange event and virtual DOM compare will fail). In render `metafield` is used but in state `metadata` is used (metfield should always be undefined with the code given). You are correct about setting the wrong part of the state though.

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutate-state-bad-y98j6) is an example of an optimized version of the app with your mutating code to show you it breaks. When you change setState to a non mutating version: `let temp = {...this.state.metadata};` it'll work again.